# Error in function circle. Bad argument #1

Tags: lua, love2d

I am trying to draw a circle in love2d. However it gives me an error (bad argument #1 to 'circle'). Here is the code...

```
win = love.window.setMode(600, 600)
love.graphics.circle( fill, 50, 50, 75 )
```

Comment: You should post what the error message is

Answer (score 1):

The word `"fill"` should be in quotation marks, because it's a String. https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.circle

```
love.graphics.circle("fill", 50, 50, 75)
```

Also as mentioned by @Sam in the comments, the above code should be placed in the `draw` function. Your window code should most likely be placed in `load`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `love.graphics.circle` should also be inside the `love.draw` function. It seems odd that it comes right after `love.window.setMode`

Comment: @Sam that’s a really great point. Should I add that to my answer?

Comment: I don't know, maybe